# Render PDF snapshot of ASP.Net MVC Bootstrap 3 printable view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a view/page with a form on it which is rendered using

- ASP.Net MVC 4.5.1 and Razor
- Bootstrap 3

I would like to be able to render a pdf snapshot of the printable view of the page as soon as the user submits the form, and save the pdf snapshot to the server for auditing purposes.

At the very least, if PDF is not possible, I should be able to render an html view, using the data that has just been submitted, and save it to disk (in .html format, for instance).

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Rotativa is pretty easy to use for creating a PDF view of what you want. It can be designed as a view on its on which you can access through any other view by creating an @Html.ActionLink.

Comment: @Scanner Thanks man... this looks promising.  Will give it a whirl to see how well it works!

Comment: Happy to help, if you get stuck with Rotativa just give me a shout

Comment: @Scanner That is exactly what I did and it worked.  Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @CraftsBeerHipsterDude glad it worked for you buddy. I'll add more to my answer tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotativa is pretty easy to use for creating a PDF view of what you want. It can be designed as a view on its on which you can access through any other view by creating an @Html.ActionLink.